# Concatenate may rows into a single text string having 2 tables

Tags: sql

Good morning. I would like to concatenate may rows into a single text string having 2 tables

**Table1**

```
ID   Use
1    A
1    A
1    B
2    A
2    B
2    C
2    B
```

**Table2**

```
ID   Cod_Sig
1    Nat
2    Nono
```

I would like to have a result like this:

```
Cod_Sig  Uso
Nat      A, B
Nono     A, B, C
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the database you're using. Also add the the query you've tried so far.

Comment: Which database are you using. and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mysql then following query will work:

```
select 
  t2.cod_sig,
  group_concat(distinct t1.use 
               order by t1.use
               separator ',') as uso
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t2.cod_sig
```

[Click here for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16115/2/0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks.I tried to run it, but it says there´s something missing.

Comment: Let me draw again the tables:
Table 1
2 fields:
ID     Use
1       A
1       A
1       B
2       A
2       B
2       C
2       B

Table2
ID   Cod_sig
1     Nat
2     Nono

Comment: The results should be like this:
Cod_sig Use
Nat         A, B
Nono      A, B, C

Comment: Are you still interested in resolving this issue?